# What is the name for numbers fonts that contain descender and ascender?

Tags: fonts

I have seen this kind of Numbers in some publications, It looks betters in the text of body, but I don't know the name or how to get them.

I am not talking about a specific font family but rather the number style.

Thanks

[image: Numbers]

Comment: I think these are called [text figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures).

Comment: There are various names - see [article here](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/oldstyle-figures#:~:text=In%20typography%2C%20the%20symbols%20used%20to%20represent%20numbers,figures%2C%20which%20are%20of%20uniform%20height%20and%20alignment.)

Comment: Not English but in French they are called *elzévirs*.

Comment: I would call them *oldstyle* figures. You need to find a font that contains them and then enable them in your layout application in the *OpenType* settings of your text. Which program do you use?

Comment: @Wolff: I am on Linux, I use Gimp.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This is what i wanted to know. Please write in the Answer section so I can close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These numbers are called [Text Figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures) or [Oldstyle Figures](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/oldstyle-figures).